# How to manage SCDF stream definition and properties?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I wonder if there is a best practice to store a stream DSL and the apps and deployer properties file associated in a SCM like Git ?
What should a Git project for a SCDF Stream look like ?
And how can we manage versions of a stream ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but, for sharing, here is what we did. Thanks *fiidim*, your answer helps us.

Our Git projects look like this :

- **apps.properties** : used to register the apps
- **definition.txt** : the DSL, used to create the stream
- **arguments.json** : deployment properties, used to deploy the stream
- **YAML files** : one for each app of the stream, with business properties

We use `Spring Cloud Config` (with *scdf* profile) for business properties of the apps, that's why we separate deployment and business properties.
We call the `SCDF` server with the REST API to register the apps, create and deploy the stream.

With a ticktock example :
**apps.properties** :

```
source.time=docker:springcloudstream/time-source-kafka:3.2.1
sink.log=docker:springcloudstream/log-sink-kafka:3.2.1
```

**definition.txt** :
`time | log`

**arguments.json** :

```
{  
  "version.time": "3.2.1",  
  "version.log": "3.2.1",  
  "app.*.spring.profiles.active": "scdf",  
  "app.*.spring.cloud.config.uri": "http://my-scc-server/config",  
  "deployer.*.kubernetes.imagePullPolicy=Always"  
}
```

**mystream-log.yml**
`log.expression: #root`

**mystream-time.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
   stream:
     poller:
       time-unit: SECONDS
       fixed-delay: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project, which deploys streams and applications to GKE, we maintain 3 separate kinds of data, all stored in native format.

1. **Application Definitions** - These are stored in a properties file as you would load into the dashboard.  One file has all definitions.  Sample line:

```
source.http=docker:springcloudstream/http-source-kafka:3.1.0
```

2. **Stream Definitions** - These are stored in the native JSON format as you would import/export from the stream dashboard.  One file has all streams, with DSLs and descriptions.  Sample:

```json
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "name": "http-router",
            "dslText": "http | inbound-router: router",
            "originalDslText": "http | inbound-router: router",
            "description": "Accept incoming requests and forwards for routing"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. **Stream Properties** - Stored as a single file per stream.  The contents format matches what you may cut and paste into the dashboard when deploying the stream.  Sample:

```
deployer.*.kubernetes.imagePullPolicy=Always
deployer.*.kubernetes.configMapRefs=ssil
app.http.path-pattern=/api
app.http.server.port=20000
app.inbound-router.router.expression=headers['destination'].toLowerCase()?:'unroutable'
```

The layout that works best for us is:

```
spring-cloud-datalow
  |- kafka-apps-docker.properties
  |- spring-cloud-streams.json
  |- stream-properties
     |- stream1.properties
     |- stream2.properties
```

Our project has all applications in one repository, so naturally the `spring-cloud-dataflow` pieces belong there, in their own folder.

Creation and deployment of these applications/streams are delegated to a script that accesses the `spring-cloud-dataflow` REST api, and minimizes usage of the dashboard.